# Do I need a separate server for Quorum?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, azure-vm

We are working on setting up AlwaysOn Availability Group for SQL Server 2014.

There will be 2 nodes: Primary Replica and Secondary Replica.

The question is, do we need a separate server for Quorum?

- All the Windows Servers are in Azure.
- As of now nothing is in place.
- The vendor stated that they will add a server for maintaining quorums.
- All servers for the complete system will be in same domain.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of points of clarification. Nodes and replicas are not the same thing. Nodes refer to the Windows Failover cluster and replicas to AvailabilityGroup instances. So assuming you are running a 2 node WSFC, each hosting a SQL instance in an AvailabilityGroup, then yes, you will need another server to achieve quorum and avoid split brain behavior. The easiest way to achieve this is simply set up a quorum file on another server outside of the cluster, known as Node and File Share majority. Read more on [WSFC Quorum Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270280.aspx).

You don't necessarily need to commission a new server for this.  Any server outside of the server will work.